# Prove a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Please, can somebody help me with this problem?

---

**[Ciarlet 5.3-1]** Let $A$ be an invertible Hermitian matrix, with the splitting $A = M-N$, $M$ being an invertible matrix. Prove that, if the Hermitian matrix $M^*+N$ is positive definite and if $\rho(M^{-1}N) := \max\{|\lambda| : \lambda\in\mbox{sp}(M^{-1}N)\} < 1$, then the matrix $A$ is positive definite.

---

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\lambda \in \mbox{sp}(M^{-1}N)$, $\exists$ nonzero eigenvector $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $$M^{-1}Nx=\lambda x \Rightarrow Nx=\lambda Mx\Rightarrow x^*Nx=\lambda x^*Mx$$ 
 We assume that 
 $$x^*Nx=p_1+\mbox{i}q_1,\quad x^*Mx=p_2+\mbox{i}q_2$$
since $M^*+N$ is positive definite, we have 
$$x^*(M^*+N)x=x^*M^*x+x^*Nx=p_2-\mbox{i}q_2+p_1+\mbox{i}q_1\geq 0$$ 
From which implies that $q_1=q_2$.

Further, since $\rho(M^{-1}N)<1$, we have $|\lambda|<1$ 
, which means $$|\frac{p_1+\mbox{i}q_1}{p_2+\mbox{i}q_2}|<1$$
 Simplifying that, then we have the following two inequalities for nonzero $x$
 $$p_1^2<p_2^2, p_1+p_2>0$$

Now, for nonzero $x$, we have
 $$x^*Ax=x^*Mx-x^*Nx=p_2-p_1$$
 Dividing into cases to consider, you will see $p_2-p_1>0$ under the restriction of the above two inequalities. Then we know $A$ is positive definite.